# Why do I get invalid syntax for else

Tags: python, if-statement

```
name=input ("please enter your name") .upper() 
names=["MARTIN","JAMES","LOUIS","BABYSHARK"]

if name==list:names
print ("You are allowed to play my game")
else
    prin ("ACCES DENIED!"))
```

Comment: You need to identify the language being used. I don't recognized this off hand.

Comment: hi I'm using python

Comment: It should be `else: print ( "ACCES DENIED!")`. Add colon after else and remove extra bracket from the end. Make sure to use proper language tags, include error text and always write code with indentation. Use backtick character or indentation to write code.

Comment: hi ive tried but still doesnt work ive included a picture in description hope its visible

Comment: Please add your code to the question instead of linking to an image.

Comment: Thanks everyone it’s now solved,mark keven solved it, but thanks for fast answers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution might be this one:

```
names=["MARTIN","JAMES","LOUIS","BABYSHARK"]
name = input('Enter your name:').upper()

if name in names:
    print('You can play my game')
else:
    print('Access Denied')
```

Comment: mark Keven thank you this solved it! Thanks for very fast answer I’m new to python and just started learning it..

Answer (score 2):

You need to add colons after your if and else statements. Also you need to indent the code in the if segment.

Comment: colons should be use in C language. Python language uses indentation

Comment: @markkeven I think you are confusing **semi**colon(;) with colon(:). C and many other languages use seimcolons to end a line. Python just uses the new line terminator. This has nothing to do with indentation. Python uses colon in several places, including with `if..else`, `while`, and `for`.

Comment: oops apologize my mistake. I thought **;** as colon

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read [the python documentation about if statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html). This clearly defines the syntax. The most common thing to miss is a colon after the condition of your `if` and after `else`.